# my /home is not mounted after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, fstab

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04
After finishing the upgrade when I rebooted the PC I get unable to mount /home press M or S
I tried M then mount -a but it does not work
in fstab I have

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=0d271cd9-4a95-4680-abd3-435bcad5eda4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda5       /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/sda1       none            swap    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb3        28G   11G   16G  40% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.2M  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  164K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            3.9G   57M  3.9G   2% /tmp/guest-k9fc5n
/dev/sdb5       416G  256G  140G  65% /media/29990594-2993-429b-a4e0-7ed7c6c26966
/dev/sda1       1.9T  1.3T  575G  70% /media/sauvegarde
/dev/sdc1       597G  517G   80G  87% /media/Serie
/dev/sdd1       233G  117G  117G  51% /media/409423EB9423E260
sw              0       0
```

while /dev/sdb5 should be the /home

Any I dea?

```
/dev/sda6       none            swap    sw              0       0
```

and in df -h

Answer (score 1):

this fix the problem

## /dev/sda5       /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

UUID=29990594-2993-429b-a4e0-7ed7c6c26966   /home   ext4    defaults    0   2