# Ubuntu upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 crashed and now /home partition won't mount at bootup

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, lubuntu, crash

I tried to upgrade my wife's Packard Bell netbook running Lubuntu 12.04 LTS to 12.10. It all ran smoothly until after the downloading of packages and requesting I confirm that some will be removed, added etc.

When I returned after leaving it to do it's thing, I had a black screen with a lot of text which unfortunately I did not note down although it was very cryptic. I do remember that it was mentioning something about the kernel, although if this is the problem I don't know.

I had to hard reboot and tried the recovery mode. I managed to get to a root shell and noticed that it is not a problem of disk space. Before the upgrade there was over 3GB on /, and now there is about 2GB. What is strange though is that the /home does not get mounted automatically at bootup. I tried various schemes as reported below to get it mounted automatically without any success.

I then tried various options such as:

fsck
dpkg
network
root
grub
system-summary = reports no /home directory

Each time it asks me to mount all the filesystem in fstab and when I confirm it stops at

```
mountall: mount /home/mywife/etc/etc/ terminated with status 1
```

it says such as in place of etc/etc/ Documents Music Media Pictures and so on.
I tried to find the solution suggested in various forums including this one but with no exact situation like mine.

Help will be much appreciated.

The /etc/fstab below:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b2c60910-ff66-4713-a629-37c293b62393 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
#/dev/sda2       none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
192.168.2.2:/home/ericam/Documents /home/ericam/media/Documents nfs timeo=14,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
192.168.2.2:/home/ericam/Pictures /home/ericam/media/Pictures nfs timeo=14,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
192.168.2.2:/home/ericam/Music /home/ericam/media/Music nfs timeo=14,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
```

This does seem a bit strange.This is the 1st time I see the /cryptswap and mounting to the ../media/.. directory!
There doesn't seem to be any older or backup fstab which would show up the differences.

running "df" as root brings up the following:

```
df: `/run/user': no such file or directory
Filesystem       1K-blocks ........ Use%    Mounted on
/dev/sda1        ..................  79%    /
udev             ..................   0%    /dev
none             ..................   1%    /run/lock
none             ..................   1%    /run/shm
```

I had to type it out so bear with the ..... bit.

Here is the output for the lsblk command:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   9.3G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0   2.8G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 220.8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1   1.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   1.9G  0 part /mnt
```

Note that sdb is the usb stick I used to copy over the data. I might add that I used the mount command.

After a few days I tried the following:

The fstab was changed to this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
#/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=d7ae9306-1dac-416e-8d59-1055ada63c48   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#/dev/sda5  /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=b2c60910-ff66-4713-a629-37c293b62393 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/sda2       none            swap    sw              0       2
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
#192.168.2.2:/home/ericam/Documents /home/ericam/media/Documents nfs timeo=14,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
#192.168.2.2:/home/ericam/Pictures /home/ericam/media/Pictures nfs timeo=14,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
#192.168.2.2:/home/ericam/Music /home/ericam/media/Music nfs timeo=14,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
```

I have amended the fstab after this questions advice:
[my /home is not mounted after 12.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125434/my-home-is-not-mounted-after-12-04-upgrade?rq=1)
I changed the lines to include the UUID which are correct. I checked...
The command 'fdisk -l' shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3e751ccc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    19531775     9764864   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       482537472   488396799     2929664   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        19533822   482535423   231500801    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        19533824   482535423   231500800   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 2002 MB, 2002780160 bytes
62 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1017 cylinders, total 3911680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001dbd4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          62     3909347     1954643    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

It still won't mount at bootup.....

Comment: Are you able to post your /etc/fstab contents?

Comment: Added to the original above.

Comment: How about output from `df` in the root prompt, to check what has been mounted?

Comment: Added to above.

Comment: Do you think it is a problem with the fstab being corrupted? You would think that during an upgrade the previous fstab would be saved as a .old or something.

Comment: I don't think fstab got corrupted, you can check if there was a backup file created. Changes to configuration sometimes cause things to not mount correctly.

Comment: You can try to replace the UUID with `/dev/sda5` to see it will mount your home directory.

Comment: I commented out everything except the /dev/sda1 line (/) in fstab, uncommented the /dev/sda2 line (swap), and added a line for /dev/sda5 as suggested above.

`/dev/sda5      /home           ext4    defaults        0       2`
It still doesn't mount the /home directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Should I have left the line with the UUID uncommented?

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: I added the lsblk output file to above text. Had to copy it onto usb stick and transfer it to another PC.

Comment: What does it say if you try to `mount` the `/home` manually?

Comment: OK. It mounts it, but how will I get it to mount it at boot time?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer or should I start another question about mounting /dev/sda5 at boot time? I guess it would be better to keep to this question as others may have similar problem stemming from the upgrade.

Comment: A more specific question about getting the disks mounted may help.

Comment: I amended the question to include the problem mounting the /home partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a way to get the /home directory to mount with instruction on this page:
[13.10 won't start after upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380253/13-10-wont-start-after-upgrading)
I will recap for brevity what worked for me:

1. Dropping to root shell in the options of the Recovery mode at bootup.
2. Run

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
3. Then

   ```
   mount --all
   ```
4. Then

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```
5. Then

   ```
   reboot
   ```
6. After the reboot ran

   ```
   apt-get -f install
   ```
7. Following this I ran the last step as described above:

   ```
   update-manager -d
   ```

Comment: Since it says 12.10 it seems like the upgrade worked at least partially. Did you try doing a normal update?

Comment: Thanks for your help Nattgew. I persisted and found the solution. I am struggling with the bluetooth now but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your `/home` to mount correctly, you should try to do a normal boot and finish the upgrade. If your sources.list has `quantal`, then do a regular update, otherwise run the upgrade again:

```
update-manager -d
```

Or, if you are unable to get to a graphical session, try from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades

Comment: I commented out everything except the /dev/sda1 line (/) in fstab, uncommented the /dev/sda2 line (swap), and added a line for /dev/sda5 as suggested above. `/dev/sda5 /home ext4 defaults 0 2` It still doesn't mount the /home directory. Any suggestions? –

Comment: I have managed to mount the /home directory. Quantal appears in the sources.list file. I would like to update but it says that not all the files have been downloaded. I tried to use the "with networking" option in the recovery menu but it needs to run fstab and then hangs. How to run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` with no internet connection?

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core` and it comes up with: `W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock    E: dpkg was interupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` When I run it it says `dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system.` Even with sudo I get the same.

Comment: Can you find an error from when it boots and fails to mount `/home/`?

Comment: A quick update on the errors at bootup:
(1) `Normal` boot: Displays lubuntu splash and hangs. (2) `FailsafeX` graphics mode: Asks to continue mounting using `/etc/fstab`. As yes is only option, continues and hangs at `fsck from util-linux 2.20.1` and `/dev/sda1: clean, .... files .... blocks` and `/dev/sda5: clean, ....`. (3) `Root terminal`: At prompt I `mount /dev/sda5 /home` which works, then `fdisk -l` shows all the partitions no problem but `df -h` there is no /dev/sda5` or `home`, but `df: /run/user: No such file or directory... /run/rpc_pipefs:..` (4) `Grub loader`: `fsck.../dev/sda`...

Comment: I have mounted the /home. See answer above. I still have problems with completing the upgrade. I am following your last step at the moment: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and will hopefully report back with positive news.